# data grid view is slow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid view which is constantly being updated. It doesn't perform the way i would like it to.

Can you guys suggest any alternative controls which you think are gonna handle updates faster?

Thanks.

////////////

no binding. when i use datasource its even worse.

i update an element like DepthGridBid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ..
i and j indexes i know from update that i receive.

---

implemented virtual mode. compared to older version. measured timing. it is not faster.

Do you guys know any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: Slow is subjective. How are you doing the updates? Is this data-bound? Unbound? Or using virtual mode? If data-bound, are updated being done per row or for the entire list?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to bind the data, and your data is changing rapidly, then virtual mode should work for you.

```
 // set the VirtualMode property to true
 dataGridView.VirtualMode = true;

 // handle the CellValueNeeded event
 dataGridView.CellValueNeeded += new
    DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView_CellValueNeeded);
```

If your data length is always the same, you only need to setup rows and columns once, and then only call Invalidate() when you receive new data, to inform DataGridView that it needs to repaint.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to query the data just in time.
please look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the most performance out of the `DataGridView` you should also take a look into the [DataGridView FAQ](http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc).